# Adding dictionaries together in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, counter

If i have 2 dictionaries `x={'a':1,'b':2}` and `y={'a':1,'b':3}`

and i want the output `z={'a':2,'b':5}`, is there a `z=dict.add(x,y)` function or should i convert both dictionaries into dataframes and then add them together with `z=x.add(y)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Counter` in this case for example:

```
from pprint import pprint
from collections import Counter

x={'a':1,'b':2}
y={'a':1,'b':3}

c = Counter()
c.update(x)
c.update(y)

pprint(dict(c))
```

Output:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 5}
```

Or using **+**:

```
from pprint import pprint
from collections import Counter

x={'a':1,'b':2}
y={'a':1,'b':3}

pprint(dict(Counter(x) + Counter(y)))
```

Comment: You can make it simpler by `c = Counter(x) + Counter(y)`

Answer (score 1):

`collections.Counter` is the natural method, but you can also use a dictionary comprehension after calculating the union of your dictionary keys:

```
x = {'a':1, 'b':2}
y = {'a':1, 'b':3}

dict_tup = (x, y)

keys = set().union(*dict_tup)
z = {k: sum(i.get(k, 0) for i in dict_tup) for k in keys}

print(z)

{'a': 2, 'b': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
from collections import Counter

x = {"a":1, "b":2}
y = {"a":1, "b":3}

c = Counter(x)
c += Counter(y)
z = dict(c)
print(z)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 5}
```